# Strange behavior of mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I ran into a problem with strange behavior of mysqli_query. There's a foreach-loop to update table rows but the update for the last loop doens't get written to the database (all the other updates get written successfully). There's no error and mysqli_affected_rows returns 1 as it should. The code pases through till the end, confirmed by an echo-statement after mysqli_query.

I tried to loop trough an array with only one element and the same problem.

What's going on here? Does anyone ran into the same problem?

OK...here's the significant part of the code, the whole code isn't possible cause there maximum 30000 characters allowed. I also echoed out the sql-string and everything is perfect. But as I said the update for the last loop (the last time when the loop is beeing executed) doesn't get written to the MySQL-DB.

```
$sql_getRelations = "SELECT id_machine, device_id, serial_number, variant_id, company_id, last_file FROM view_machines "
        . "WHERE company_id NOT IN ('" . implode( '\',\'' , $btc_companies) . "') "
//        . "AND id_machine = 158 "
        . "AND device_type_id = 4 AND machine_status = 'active' "
        . "ORDER BY id_machine ASC;";
$result_relations = mysqli_query($db_ed, $sql_getRelations);
$relations_arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result_relations, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_free_result($result_relations);

foreach($relations_arr as $machine){
    //...some other code here
    $sql_update_device = "UPDATE device SET last_file = '" . $str_max_ts . "' WHERE id_device = " . $machine['device_id'] . ";";
    $update_device = mysqli_query($db_ed, $sql_update_device);
    if (!$update_device) {
        error_log("\r\n" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ': !!!!Updatefehler device: ' . $machine['device_id'] . ": " . mysqli_error($db_ed), 3, "C:/xampp/htdocs/cronjob/error_log.txt");
    }
    echo $machine['id_machine'] . ', ';
}
mysqli_close($db_ed);
```

Comment: create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok..I'll see what I can do

Comment: if all other updates run, then something is failing and some of your columns are accepting probable null/empty values. It's hard to say since we have no code to work with. You'll need to post all code that is relevant and the db schema also. It might be failing "silently" due to column lengths being too short also.

Comment: *the whole code isn't possible cause there maximum 30000 characters allowed* sure, that's because you need to update a **MINIMAL** complete, verifiable example. Not a lengthy code for people to dig through on their way to the error.

Comment: I edited the question and posted the significant code...any ideas?

Comment: We closed this   at the state of Rev1 of it when you said basically "I refuse to show my code" ... ( not with an evil tone ) . This version now, we don't even know if you are connected, if you have Error Reporting activated, etc. PHP is happy to just die without you heeding its messages.

Comment: obviously there's no error in the code (otherwise the other updates wouldn't get written succesfully)...I think it's more a sistematical problem here (mysqli_affected_rows = 1). The question is if anyone had a similar problem with updating via mysqli_query? Maybe the update needs more time to get written before the code finishes...no idea

Comment: I'm not a professional programmer and sometimes I don't understand what you guy's really want from me. I do my best to explain the problem the most precise way I can and also try to respond to the comments in the best way I can. But maybe you could be a bit more patient as not every user at Stackoverflow is a professional...thank you

Comment: `mysqli_affected_rows` -> you aren't calling it (if you are you aren't showing it). You aren't showing data before and after. And I am not sure what you mean by `the last loop` when you only have 1 loop (shown). There is no reason why you can't flush out to a debugging text file the status of calls after them, and stage your data with a before and after view even if for your own consumption. Setting up a quality question like your problem would require a lot of effort. Most people really aren't into that

Comment: ok...I gonna write a simple test-code and try to post it here again. I don't know what you mean by _flush out to a debugging text file the status of calls after them_ what is status of calls?

Comment: I don't get notified in my inbox unless you @Drew me

Comment: @Drew: I wrote a test code but obviously it wasn't possible to reproduce this error...what can I do to trace this error? My expertise ends with `mysqli_error` and `mysqli_affected_rows`....

Comment: @Drew: to explain the funcionality: I'm importing data to my database via web-service (SOAP). This script runs every 5 minutes. To import only files which haven't been imported yet I need to update a timestamp-string `$str_max_ts` in my device-table (field _last_file_) after the import. So the next time the script gets executed it only imports files with a timestamp higher than the one which is saved in the device-table for each device. What happens is that the script runs through over all devices and after import updates the _last_file_ field but not for the last device in the foreach-loop.

Comment: @Drew: maybe we can interchange emails and I mail you the whole code?

Comment: sure I am drewpierce747 gmail

Answer (score 1):

I would perform debugging like the following to a text file. Wedge your data collection in the outer loops then rem that out and zero in on inner chunks. A divide and conquer strategy.

I would have tried to get my head into your email php but it is 675 lines of one foreach block :p

PHP:

```
<?php
    //mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_ALL); // report all PHP errors.
    ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
    echo "start<br/>";

    // $file="/home/nate/debug123.txt";
    $file="c:\\nate\\debug123.txt";
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');


    $debugStr=date('Y-m-d H:i:s').": Start";
    file_put_contents($file, $debugStr."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    try {
        $mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'theUser', 'thePassword', 'theDB_Name');
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        echo "I am connected and feel happy.<br/><br/>";

        $query = "INSERT INTO `t921`(`thing`,`uniqueNum`,`views`) values ('aaa',577,0)"; // change that 577 each time else it fails unique
        echo $query."<br>";
        $mysqli->query($query);
        $debugStr=date('Y-m-d H:i:s').": Affected rows: " .$mysqli->affected_rows.", Insert id: ".$mysqli->insert_id;
        echo $debugStr."<br><br>";
        file_put_contents($file, $debugStr."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

        $query = "UPDATE `t921` SET `views`=`views`+1 WHERE id=1";
        echo $query."<br>";
        $mysqli->query($query);
        $id=1;
        $debugStr=date('Y-m-d H:i:s').": UPDATE id=".$id.", Affected rows: " . $mysqli->affected_rows;
        echo $debugStr."<br><br>";
        file_put_contents($file, $debugStr."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

        $query = "UPDATE `t921` SET `views`=`views` WHERE id=1";
        echo $query."<br>";
        $mysqli->query($query);
        $id=1;
        $debugStr=date('Y-m-d H:i:s').": UPDATE id=".$id.", Affected rows: " . $mysqli->affected_rows;
        echo $debugStr."<br><br>";
        file_put_contents($file, $debugStr."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

        $mysqli->close();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    }
?>
```

Sample log file (debug123.txt):

```
2016-09-19 18:23:57: Start
2016-09-19 18:23:57: Affected rows: 1, Insert id: 27
2016-09-19 18:23:57: UPDATE id=1, Affected rows: 1
2016-09-19 18:23:57: UPDATE id=1, Affected rows: 0
```

Note the last update stmt was meant to change no data thus affected=0

Schema:

```
create table t921
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null,
    uniqueNum int not null,
    views int not null,
    unique key(uniqueNum)
);
```